# Elasticsearch field name case sensitive

Tags: elasticsearch, case-sensitive

I am looking for advise and best practice regarding field name case sensitivity in ElasticSearch and whether there is a global configuration to make field names case insensitive.
Also, if it is possible to disable ES from adding different fields if it does not exists in the mapping.

here is an example to illustrate the point;

1- create mapping with one field "name" in lowercase

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/twitter/user/_mapping -d '{ 
        "user" : { 
            "properties" : { 
            "name" : { "type" : "string" } 
        } 
    } 
}'
```

2- Index a document, using a different case for the name field (NAME)

```
curl -POST http://localhost:9200/twitter/user/1 -d '{ 
   "NAME" :  "Yasir" 
}'
```

In the Elasticsearch logs, I noticed that the mapping is updated.

```
[2014-01-26 20:58:19,074][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Mad-Dog] [twitter] update_mapping [user] (dynamic)
```

3- check the mapping, you will notice a new field has been added "NAME"

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/twitter/user/_mapping?pretty

{
  "user" : {
    "properties" : {
      "NAME" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks
Yasir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disbale the automatic creation of the mapping in the configs, like mentioned [in the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation).

Just set `action.auto_create_index` to `false`.

The field names can not be case-insensitive, since the naming belongs to you. I would suggest to only use lowercase for that. However, you can search in your values case-insensitive.

**EDIT:**

Like @javanna's comment says, this does not disable the [dynamic mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html).
Therefore, you have to set `index.mapper.dynamic` to `false`.

As a result, non declared fields will be ignored. 
If you want elasticsearch to throw an error instead, you have to set it to `strict`.

Comment: What you suggested disabled the creation of a new index when you index the first document under a non existing field. If you want to disable dynamic mapping, so that the mappings are not created automatically (but you have to define the schema upfront) you can set `index.mapper.dynamic` to `false`. As a result, non declared fields will be ignored. If you want elasticsearch to throw an error instead, set it to `strict`. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html

Comment: You're welcome, maybe you can rephrase your answer accordingly as it is not completely correct? ;)