# Elasticsearch documents not searchable

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, indexing, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I've created a simple index in my Elasticsearch domain via Kibana on AWS Elasticsearch using below PUT command:

```
PUT sals_poc_test_20210217
{
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 10,
        "number_of_replicas" : 1,
        "max_result_window": 50000,
        "max_rescore_window": 50000
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "ID_NUMBER": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
        "CLASS_NAME": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
        "PUBLISHER_ID": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "INGESTION_DATE": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
        },
        "DECISION": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "ID": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then I've put one document into this index:

```
{
  "id_number" : "guvqlsxz",
  "class_name" : "/TEST_1/sample_1",
  "publisher_id" : "1234",
  "ingestion_date" : "2021-02-12 16:48:57.503665",
  "decision" : "yes",
  "id" : "0958741792"
}
```

Then I tried to search this document by any of the above 6 fields, none of them returned me this document.
Sample search command below:

```
POST /sals_poc_test_20210217/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term": { "id_number": "guvqlsxz"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I retrieve all using below command:

```
POST /sals_poc_test_20210217/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_index": "sals_poc_test_20210217"
    }
  }
}
```

all documents returned up nicely.

Could anyone shed any light as of why searching by these indexed fields not working?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked the docs, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369465/elasticsearch-field-name-case-sensitive) indicates that field names are case-sensitive by default.

Comment: I tried both, no luck.

Comment: I tried exact same commands in two different version of elastic search, and working in both. can you add which version of Elastic search you are using and how you are inserting document to index.

Comment: Thanks @BaluVyamajala, I figured out: it's the way that I inserted documents is problematic: I formed an extra layer of `data` before indexing, after removing this layer, it's fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @FisherCoder I think I'm having the same problem... Where was the extra layer? I'm not seeing it... Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

> You can disable dynamic mapping, both at the document and at the
> object level. Setting the dynamic parameter to false ignores new
> fields, and strict rejects the document if Elasticsearch encounters an
> unknown field.

As mentioned in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25825), the false option for the dynamic setting accepts documents that have fields that are not in the mapping (i.e. it will not throw an error) but it will not index those fields so you won't be able to search those fields.

Comment: ok, I've removed this line: `"dynamic": "false",` and created a new index and retried, still not searchable..

Comment: @FisherCoder I tried with the same above index mapping and search query, **after removing `"dynamic": "false"`, and now the fields are searchable**, as now the field mapping for the lowercase fields are also created dynamically.